# Scala, PlayFramework - No implicit Format available for Any

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit

I have a case class and implicit format as below:

```
case class Foo(x:String, y:Any)
implicit val fooFormat = Json.format[Foo]
```

and I want to convert class Foo to Json, However, I am getting error **No implicit format Any available**.

```
val foo = Foo("apple", 12)
println(Json.toJson(foo))
[error] Test.scala:33: No implicit format for Any available.
[error]     implicit val fooFormat = Json.format[Foo]
```

So, how can I provide implicit format for type Any?

Comment: How do you expect it to be serialized? Since `Any` could be (literally) anything, it may have very different possible serialization. BTW, if you want only serialization, you should use `Json.writes[Foo]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide writes explicitly and handle the cases in which `Any` can be Int, Long, Float, Double, String, Boolean etc

```
case class Foo(x:String, y:Any)

implicit val writes = new Writes[Foo] {
  override def writes(o: Foo): JsValue = {
    Json.obj("x" -> o.x) ++ {
      o.y match {
        case a: Int => Json.obj("y" -> a)
        case a: Long => Json.obj("y" -> a)
        case a: Float => Json.obj("y" -> a)
        case a: Double => Json.obj("y" -> a)
        case a: String => Json.obj("y" -> a)
        case a: Boolean => Json.obj("y" -> a)
        case a => Json.obj("y" -> a.toString)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> Json.toJson(Foo("foo", true))
res5: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"x":"foo","y":true}

scala> Json.toJson(Foo("foo", 1.toFloat))
res6: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"x":"foo","y":1}

scala> Json.toJson(Foo("foo", (1.131313).toFloat))
res7: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"x":"foo","y":1.1313129663467407}

scala> Json.toJson(Foo("foo", (1.131313).toDouble))
res8: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"x":"foo","y":1.131313}
```